# One laptop can access internet via iPhone hotspot, other cannot

Tags: wireless-networking

I have two Windows 10 laptops adjacent to my iPhone SE hotspot.  Both can connect to the hotspot.  Laptop #1 can access the internet, laptop #2 cannot.

On laptop #2, the hotspot shows up as as the name "iPhone" and "No internet, secured".  When I click the "Properties" link on each laptop, all fields are identical except:

```
Property                Laptop #1      Laptop #2
----------------------- -------------- ---------
Link-local IPv6 address <hex digits>   <hex digits>
IPv4 address            172.20.10.2    172.20.10.3
IPv4 DNS servers        172.20.10.1    192.168.1.1
Description             See [1] below  See [2] below
Driver version          19.51.35.2     22.140.0.3
Physical address (MAC)  <hex digits>   <hex digits>
```

On laptop #2, the leading elements of the "IPv4 DNS servers" do not match those of the IPv4 address, which doesn't make sense to me.  I rebooted the laptop and reconnected to the hotspot, but this disparity remains.

**Am I right in that the disparity doesn't make sense?  If so, how can I prevent this?  If not, then what else could explain laptop #2's inaccessibility to the internet?**

Note that if I connect both laptops to a home Wi-Fi network, then both can access the internet.  I do not use custom firewalls.  Laptop #1 uses Symantec Endpoint Protection while laptop #2 uses Bitdefender.

**NOTES**

[1] Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz

[2] Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed above a DNS issue, have you tried entering a manual DNS server such as 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 or both?

I would suspect that would fix it. This wouldn't affect the laptop connecting to the wifi at home and will still work if left manually configured this way. I think this is just a limitation in the iPhone's hotspot but unfortunately, I have no experience in it.

Is the iPhone on the latest IOS version?

Comment: Manually specifying 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 as primary and secondary DNS servers, respectively, has worked. If it is an iPhone hotspot limitation, it is a very obscure one, as it doesn't afflict both laptops. Both laptops have Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19044 Build 19044 and I update whenever prompted. I also update the iPhone whenever prompted. It's at iOS 15.6.1. There is a 15.7, which I'll upgrade to when I'm in a non-nomadic environment for an extended duration, but I don't have hopes that the one most recent update will resolve this rather obscure issue. Thanks for your fix!

Comment: Because of the above observations, I believe that it may be a Windows 10 issue, driver issue, for firmware issue on the laptop.

Comment: Glad it fixed it! Another thing to try is to see if you can manually configure the DNS servers on the iPhone's hotspot. Again trying 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 or again both. Then of course setting the pc to automatically detect this rather than manually being set and see how it behaves.

Comment: I browsed the iPhone GUI for its hotspot functionality, but haven't found my way to DNS parameters. Regarding the suggestion to make the PC automatically detect the DNS server, I guess that's what this question boils down to.  I'm not a "network" guy, nor knowledgeable about the architecture of firmware or lower level software (or even software in general).  I can probably get enough understanding with an astronomical amount of time commitment, but unfortunately, can't do that at the moment.  It could boil down to an adapter design deficiency.  I'm grateful for the quick fix that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

On laptop 2, 192.168.1.1 seems to be the dns from your home network. Check if this is set manually and if yes, change to automatic.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn12X.png]

Comment: Yes, the radio button for "Obtain DNS server address automatically" is enabled.  So that would not be the cause of the problem.  That button is enabled regardless of whether I'm connected to my (bro's) home Wi-Fi or to my iPhone's hotspot.